# Displaying image content types as grids in drupal 7?

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am currently using the Views and Display Suite modules to create a page that works as an image gallery. You click on the menu button to take you to a page (the view) that has multiple links to nodes (individual galleries).

When you click these nodes, they take you into the separate page and show all images uploaded using the "event" content type that I made.

The event content type has one field (type: image) that uses a multiupload widget, allowing for multiple file uploads.

However, the images on the node are displayed within divs, so they all have their own rows basically. I would like to know if it was possible to put them all into grids, and if so; how? I tried using display suite, but I only have that one field to work with.

Comment: Maybe try looking at this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap it makes it responsive too.

Comment: @Stefan That provided with me an alternative solution, but still not what I wanted to do. I want to arrange the content of fields inside the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a fully customized page and arrange the fields just like you want, use the **[theme suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)**.

For a node of type "event", as you said, it would be `node--event.tpl.php`. You can duplicate the code inside the base template `node.tpl.php` of your parent theme (or if you don't have one, of Bartik for example) to have a good starting material.

Just rearrange the div, the tags, the variables as your convenience, add some custom CSS to make your grid, and you should be done!

I hope it helps.